# Angular2 template - use variable not on this

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-template

Is it possible to use a variable in an Angular 2 template that is not on the `this` context?

For example:

```
<div>{{ fooBar }}</div>
```

`fooBar` needs to be defined in the class used by this component somewhere, like:

```
export class MyComponent {
  public fooBar: boolean = true;
}
```

But what if you just want to use a value that's not on the class? For example, maybe you want to import a list of string constants and display them selectively in the template:

```
import { MyService } from './my.service'; 
import { StringConstants } from '../string.constants';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
    <div *ngIf="isPrimary">{{ StringConstants.PRIMARY }}</div>
    <div *ngIf="isSecondary">{{ StringConstants.SECONDARY }}</div>
  `
})

export class MyComponent {
  public isPrimary: boolean;
  public isSecondary: boolean;

  constructor (private myService: MyService) {
    this.isPrimary = myService.getPrimaryContext();
    this.isSecondary = myService.getSecondaryContext();
  }
};
```

Comment: Just assign that list to a class variable?

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways to achieve it:

1) Define variable in component with the same name as your constant

```
export class MyComponent {
  StringConstants = StringConstants;
  ...
```

2) Use es6 string interpolation

```
template:`
  <div *ngIf="isPrimary">${StringConstants.PRIMARY}</div>
  <div *ngIf="isSecondary">${StringConstants.SECONDARY}</div>
`
export class MyComponent {
```

Comment: To be clear: looks like option 2 will only work if the template is inlined, not external.